# package listed in `list-packages' but get `Error during download request: Not Found`

Tags: package-repositories, use-package, js2-mode

This is the value of my `package-archives` variable:

```
C-h v package-archives
package-archives's value is (("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")
                         ("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
```

When I do a `M-x list-packages` I see package `js2-mode` but when I try to install it I get:

```
Error during download request: Not Found
```

I also have the following in my `.emacs` :

```
 (use-package js2-mode
    :mode "\\.js\\'"
    :ensure t)
```

but when I visit a `*.js` buffer (with `--init-debug`) I get the following trace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Error during download request: Not Found")                                 
   signal(error ("Error during download request: Not Found"))                                                     
   error("Error during download request:%s" " Not Found")                                                         
  package-handle-response()                                                                                      
  package-download-tar(js2-mode "20151027.456")                                                                  
  package-download-transaction((js2-mode))                                                                       
  package-install(js2-mode)                                                                                      
  use-package-ensure-elpa(js2-mode)                                                                              
  use-package-handler/:ensure(js2-mode :ensure t (:mode (("\\.js\\'" . js2-mode)) :config (t) :defer t) nil)     
  use-package-process-keywords(js2-mode (:ensure t :mode (("\\.js\\'" . js2-mode)) :config (t) :defer t))        
  #[(name &rest args) "\306^H\235?\205\317^@    ;\203^R^@\307   !\202^S^@       ^Z\310  ^H\"\311\312^[^\^]\313^M$
  (use-package js2-mode :mode "\\.js\\'" :ensure t)                                                              
  (progn (require (quote package)) (setq package-enable-at-startup nil) (mapc (function (lambda (p) (add-to-list$
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/mperdikeas/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 25263         
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/mperdikeas/.emacs" "/home/mperdikeas/.emacs" t t)                             
  load("~/.emacs" t t)                                                                                           
  #[0 "^H\205\262^@     \306=\203^Q^@\307^H\310Q\202;^@ \311=\204^^^@\307^H\312Q\202;^@\313\307\314\315#\203*^@\$
  command-line()                                                                                                 
  normal-top-level()
```

**update**

See [my "answer"](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17761/4003) below.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP declared it to be a non-issue.

Comment: It just saved my day in a similar situation, plus it's not off-topic, please keep this open

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: `M-x package-refresh-contents` and try again :)

Emacs tells you that a package was not found on the remote archive.  This is a symptom of an outdated local package archive cache: Your Emacs tries to fetch an outdated version of a package which does not exist on the server anymore because a never package is already available.  You can refresh the local cache with `M-x package-refresh-contents`.

This is specifically an issue with MELPA, because unlike GNU ELPA it does not keep a backlog of older releases: Every update of a package deletes all older releases.

Hence you really need to make sure that your package archive cache is update if you are using MELPA.

Comment: I did that, same thing. I already have `(package-refresh-contents)` in my `.emacs`.

Comment: Are you _sure_ that `package-refresh-contents` is actually called?  The current version of JS2 Mode on MELPA is `20151029.1946`. Try to refresh manually with `M-x package-refresh-contents`.

Comment: Even after manually `M-x package-refresh-contents` this is what appears on the `list-packages`:  `js2-mode           20151027.456 available  Improved JavaScript editing mode` (and installing it fails again with the same message). I can access MELPA repo just fine with a browser, but could it be that the installation uses some other port as well that my firewall blocks?

Answer (score 0):

Without changing anything, after a couple of hours it started working again. Some network vagary I suppose.